# How to use require_relative with an rspec test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, require, before-filter

I have an rspec test, i.e. describe and an it

I want to add `before :all` and `before :each` behavior

I can add it by putting in the test spec file directly, i.e.

```
describe "test" do
  before :all do
    CONTINUE_SPEC= true
  end

  around :each do |example|
    if CONTINUE_SPEC
      CONTINUE_SPEC = false
      example.run
      CONTINUE_SPEC = true unless example.exception
    else
      example.skip
    end
  end
  ... actual tests...
```

However I want to have it in nearly every spec so I thought I could use a `require_relative` statement to make it easy.  However when I transfer the code to a file using require_relative with

```
require_relative '../../support/continue_test_if_passing'
```

I get

```
Failure/Error:
  before :all do
    CONTINUE_SPEC= true
  end

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `before' for main:Object
```

Comment: I know that `require` is always executed at the top level of the Ruby script (the `main` special object) even if it is called from a deeper level or encapsulated in something. That's why you receive the error `undefined method 'before' for main:Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your `spec_helper.rb` in the `RSpec.configure` block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :all do
    CONTINUE_SPEC= true
  end

  config.around :each do |example|
    if CONTINUE_SPEC
      CONTINUE_SPEC = false
      example.run
      CONTINUE_SPEC = true unless example.exception
    else
      example.skip
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```